# clickable or active a parent menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, parent

How do I have to make clickable or active a parent menu in wordpress. Each menu that has sub menu is no longer clickable or inactive. what should I do to solve this problem?
thank you for helping me

Comment: What theme do you use? Many themes have lots of settings for their menus. And if you seek to do the clickable state yourself then look into jQuery or Javascript

Comment: please try to add what you have tried or add some code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please follow this to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage by adding a filter :

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```